# « Bébé » et autres termes formés par redoublement de syllabe

Tags: formulation, terminologie, noms

On parle de *redoublement hypocoristique de la première syllabe* pour des termes qui existent sans cette première syllabe, par exemple « sousoupe », « cucul ».

([TLfi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sousoupe))  **sousoupe** subst.  fém., fam., synon. [Avec redoublement hypocor. de la 1re syll.]

Pour ces termes qui sont formés selon le principe de la rétention de la première syllabe d'un terme avec un redoublement on parle *d'euphémisme ou de langage enfantin* : « caca » , « pipi » (pisse),…

Pour un terme comme « bébé », l'étymologie ne semble pas être fondée sur l'anglais « baby », que l'on trouve bien avant.

([etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=baby)) […] French bébé (19c.) is said to be from English, but there were similar words in the same sense in French dialects.

([TLFi, ÉTYMOL. ET HIST.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A9b%C3%A9))  − Ca 1755 nom donné par le roi Stanislas à son nain Nicolas Ferry (1739-64) qui eut à l'époque une grande célébrité; 1793, 27 févr. mon bébé « mon petit » terme d'affection (E. et J. de Goncourt, Sophie Arnould, Lettre de Sophie Arnould à Bélanger, Paris, 1877, pp. 103-104 : « Eh bien, mon bébé [...] je compterai éternellement sur ton cœur [...] Ah çà, mon bébé, je hasarde toutes ces demandes [...] Bonjour, mon bon bébé, mon ancien et éternel ami : n'oublie jamais qu'il existe dans un coin de cette terre un être qui t'a aimé bien tendrement); 1858 « petit enfant » (Goncourt, Journal dans Bonn. : Les beaux yeux de son bébé et son babil d'oiseau); 1885 « poupée représentant un enfant au maillot » (Lami, De l'indust., t. 5, 964, ibid., 8 : Le bébé nouveau est en cartonnage moulé). Malgré son attest. tardive, formation fr. (cf. Littré; FEW t. 1, p. 304; Bl.-W.5) du rad. onomatopéique beb- var. de bab- (babiller*, babine*; cf. babi, Bas-Maine; bibi, Picardie, Centre, Midi; bobée, Reims; babré, bobré, Moselle cités comme onomatopéiques dans I. Pauli, v. bbg. § 376) peut-être sous l'infl. de be- (bêler* et même bel*, cf. bellot « enfant » dans de nombreux dial. v. I. Pauli, op. cit. § 176), plutôt qu'adaptation de l'angl. baby « id. » (Bonn., p. 8; Mack. t. 1, pp. 285-286; Barb., v. bbg.; DG; Nyrop t. 1, p. 116; I. Pauli, op. cit. § 392; DEI; Dauzat 1973) v. baby, qui a pu cependant exercer une infl. second. sur la diffusion du mot dans la société cultivée; bébé a pénétré aussi en ital. moderne.

Il s'agit donc d'une répétition de syllabe qui n'est pas due à une langue d'emprunt, sans idée de créer un euphémisme, ni de produire du langage enfantin ; c'est d'ailleurs du langage d'adulte.

Existe-t-il un nom pour ce procédé de formation des noms ?

Existe-t-il un terme pour les noms de plus de deux syllabes qui sont formés par répétition de la première syllabe, sans qu'il y ait une intention de produire un euphémisme, par exemple « bibine ».

(TLFi, ÉTYMOL. ET HIST. − 1. Cf. supra A, 1862 (Hugo, Les Misérables, t. 1, p. 796); [début xixes. d'apr. Dauzat 1973, Lar. Lang. fr. et Pt Rob.]; 2. cf. supra B, 1890, 22 janv. (Père Peinard, p. 2 dans Sain. Lang. par., p. 352 : Du piccolo nature au lieu de tord-boyaux et de la sale bibine des bistros). Altération d'apr. cantine, cuisine d'un rad. bib- expr. tiré plutôt de biberon2(d'apr. forge/forgeron) que directement du lat. bibere; la chronol. des emplois fr. interdit d'y voir une altération de l'ital. bibita « boisson composée de sirop ou de jus de fruit » (Dauzat 1973, Lar. Lang. fr., Pt Rob.).)

Comment: As the etymology quoted shows, bébé is not the result of reduplication.

Answer (score 1):

Le procédé de formation des mots par la répétition de la première syllabe est appelé « redoublement hypocoristique de la première syllabe ».

En ce qui concerne les noms de plus de deux syllabes formés par la répétition de la première syllabe, il n'existe pas de terme spécifique dans la langue française pour décrire ce phénomène.

Je ne vois donc pas d'autres termes que ce dernier pour définir cette situation :

**mots formés par redoublement de la première syllabe**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Quant aux noms de plus de deux syllabes formés par la répétition de la première syllabe sans intention d'euphémisme, je ne trouve pas un terme spécifique.

Je propose décrire ce processus comme, tout simplement, un **redoublement syllabique non euphémistique**.

Answer (score 0):

Cela s'appelle officiellement

**une réduplication syllabique hypocoristique**

D'après Wikipédia, «hypocoristique» est un mot qui exprime une affection tendre, adressé au destinataire de la communication ou désignant un être ou un objet dont parle le locuteur. Le mot vient du grec ὑποκορισμός qui signifie diminution. En grec moderne, ὑποκοριστικό est justement un diminutif.